# Codeship build failing attempting to install drush

Tags: drupal, drush, codeship

We are using CodeShip to deploy our Drupal project to our staging and production servers but recently ran into a weird error that I can't quite figure out. After codeship clones our repo, it attempts to download drush (in the Test Setup Commands) with the set up command:

```
phpenv local 7.2
composer global require drush/drush:8.*
```

The error is a GitHub API Limit error (our repo is on Bitbucket) when attempting to install webmozart. here is the exact output:

```
Changed current directory to /home/rof/.config/composer
10:15
./composer.json has been updated
10:15
Loading composer repositories with package information
10:15
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
10:15
Package operations: 20 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
10:15
  - Installing webmozart/path-util (2.3.0): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           GitHub API limit (0 calls/hr) is exhausted, could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/webmozart/path-util/zipball/d939f7edc24c9a1bb9c0dee5cb05d8e859490725. Create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit. You can also wait until ? for the rate limit to reset.
10:15

10:15
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+bionic_1c08b812-722b-4de8-8cfb-cf1cfd4f8a90_6387dcd5d7c9+2020-03-25+2025
10:15
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "/home/rof/.config/composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
10:15
Token (hidden): 
10:15

10:15

10:15
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:15
  This command didn't output anything for 10 minutes, thus we stopped it.
10:15
  Please make sure your steps regularly print to standard out or standard error.
10:15
  If the error is on our end please inform us so we can help you to fix this.
10:15
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------composer global require drush/drush:8.*
```

We have had this running for a couple of years and in the last month this issue has regularly occurred. Whats stranger it that sometimes it errors and other times it works perfectly fine...

Any ideas on how to resolve this?